# Combining both a sticky and floating navbar with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm mocking up a navbar based on what I saw used on the EA GAMES website. I'm getting it to work fine in Chrome, but cannot get it to not look like garbage in IE. I'm looking for tips on how I might get this to work, if I even can?

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/okaykaylyn/pen/bQWXqq

```
<!--   Fixed top    -->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-end" id="fix_nav">
<a class="navbar-brand ml-auto" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href=""><i class="fas fa-cog"></i></a>

</nav>


<!--   floating nav    -->
<div class="container col-12">
<nav class="mt-3 navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg rounded" id="float_nav">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> 
<img src="https://image.ibb.co/cZBKcq/Asset-2.png" id="logo"></a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link text-left d-flex" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Accounts
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My Accounts</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Agency Accounts</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Indications</a>
    </div>
  </li>
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Tools
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Products & Applications</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Claims Examples</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Reports</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fun</a>
    </div>
   </li>      
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      About
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Team</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">News</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Charity</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Relevant info: EA doesn't even let IE users view their website. Not sure if this is the reason why...

Comment: What is the question? What is not working with the code you've tried?

Comment: @Zim think I may've left out a closing tag on accident the first time- the problem I was having was that when I ran this code in IE from desktop, it looked like an amorphous blob at the top of the screen. When I tried again yesterday, however, it looked fine. Not sure if there's an option to delete the question... ^^;

Answer (score 0):

You could see from [MDN documentation about justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content#Support_in_Flex_layout) that IE does not support justify-content-end attribute.
That is why it looks not well in IE.

I've tested your code and find that in your situation, you just have to remove the justify-content-end attribute and it will work well both on Chrome and IE as before.

[image: running result in IE11]